# Mining feathercoins in ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, gpu

I would like to get started on mining some feathercoins but I have no idea where to start.
Does anyone know a good guide on how I can set up a feathercoin wallet and then mine them with my gtx 760?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to do some research.  Is the GTX 760 OpenCL compatible?  If it is, then you'll be able to mine, and some people can help get you started.  If you can't, then you can't mine.  Either way, this site is probably going to be a bit limited in how it can help you.  Also, don't use the [tag:bitcoin] tag for non-Bitcoin posts.

Comment: Google is your friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current client is at the bottom of [this page](http://software.opensuse.org/package/feathercoin) at the Feathercoin site.

The [official forum](http://forum.feathercoin.com/) will likely have discussion of wallet apps.

And, although your graphics card is OpenCL compatible, it was [optimized for gaming, not number crunching](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/geforce-gtx-760-review-gk104,3542-20.html), so it may not be as fast as you like.

Comment: So I downloaded the home:p_conrad:coins file from the feathercoin site, but when running the deb file I get a message in the software centre telling me that dependency libboost-filesystem1.53.0 isn't installed. I tried apt-get install but that doesn't work. Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: The official forum is the place to ask for support on their software, as it's pretty new and, well, if anyone here knew anything about it, they would have answered by now.